how do i apply nativewind/ tailwind styling across my entire react-native (expo) application?
i have been having issues where i cant see the theme that i have implemented for my react native expo project. I'm not sure what is causing the issue... for reference, no nativewind styling is showing.
My tailwind.config.js looks like this:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const nativewind = require("nativewind/tailwind/native")
module.exports = {
  // NOTE: Update this to include the paths to all of your component files.
  content: [
    "./*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./app/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  presets: [require("nativewind/preset")],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        purple: {
          default: '#dba4eb',
          light: '#f5d0fe',
          dark: '#62a839',
        },
        'midnight': {
          default:'#9866ea',
          light:'#58055a',
          dark: '#3c0764',
        },
        pink: {
        default: '#ea66cd',
        light: '#f77ce3',
        dark: '#bb2aa4',
        },

        fuchsia: {
          default: '#c026d3',
          light: '#f0abfc',
          dark: '#4a044e'
        },

        'dark': '#76199e',
        'soft-dark': '#2A2A2F', 
        'green': '#32a852',
        'white': '#f5f7f6',
      },
      spacing: {
        '2x': '20px',
        '3x': '30px',
      },
      borderRadius: {
        '4xl': '40px',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("nativewind/babel")],
}

and my babel.config.js looks like this
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      ["babel-preset-expo", { jsxImportSource: "nativewind" }],
      
    ],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
  };
};

my file structure looks like this
(with the pages directory sitting in the same directory as my tailwind.config.js. I essentially need the styles to be applied to all of the components in my pages directory.
I have tried resetting the cache, reinstalling nativewind and tailwind but this doesn't work.
I'd be very grateful to hear anyone's thoughts on resolving the issue.
Alternatively, is it better to use an alternative to Nativewind when styling with React Native?

you can check my article on tailwind css it may help you:
https://medium.com/@aqeel_ahmad/tailwind-css-in-react-native-2024-ac4cc7973446

thank you @AqeelAhmad , i have implemented the set up as you've mentioned - including the plugins for the babel.config. it is still not working unfortunately
